# Getting the count of names with date in pdf

Tags: php, mysql, date, count, fpdf

The following code is used by me to generate a pdf inorder to display the number of customer registration with the date!

```
  <?php
    require_once("db.php"); //database connection php script

    require("fpdf/fpdf.php");

    $sql="Select count(Name) as Names,date from datetest";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $pdf=new PDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $pdf-> Cell("",20," ".$row['Names'].$row['date'],1,10);
    }

    $pdf->output();
    ?>
```

The final result of this code yields only a single date and the total number of names! But i want to display the number of names of users registered on each day! How can i correct this?

Comment: Thanx thats not the major issue i need to get the number of users on a daily basis but currently it gives only total number of users and the top most date! Though there are several dates in the table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `GROUP BY`.  Use this query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Names, DATE(date) date FROM datetest GROUP BY DATE(date);
```

This will work if your `date` column has the `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or  `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
Select count(Name) as Names,date from datetest GROUP BY date
```